# .NET Creating a Semaphore fails with IoException on Win 2008

Tags: .net, semaphore, ioexception

The following code is failing for me on Windows 2008. It succeeds in Win7.

```
return new Semaphore(1, 1, "my-test-semaphore");
```

I get the following error:

```
System.IO.IOException: The specified port does not exist.
  at System.IO.Ports.InternalResources.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String str)
  at System.IO.Ports.InternalResources.WinIOError()
  at System.Threading.Semaphore..ctor(Int32 initialCount, Int32 maximumCount, String name)
  at Throttle.Program.CreateSemaphore(String passthroughApplication)
  at Throttle.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

I've searched around and can't find an explanation. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are the victim of a bug in the error reporting.  The exception message is strange because the WinIOError() method it uses is shared with the SerialPort class.  When the Windows error code is 2 (File not found) or 3 (Path not found) then you get the exception message that's only appropriate for a serial port.  Thus the weirdo "The specified port does not exist" message.

I am a victim of your code snippet, you obfuscated the real problem.  The semaphore name you used isn't actually "my-test-semaphore".  I can't guess what it really looks like but it violates the rules for a properly named Windows object.  It might look like `"backslashes\\are not okay"`.

Fix the semaphore name.

Comment: Bug submitted: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/811441/bad-exception-message-for-improper-semaphore-name

Comment: Wow. That's all I have to say. Wow. I can't find semaphore naming limitations documented anywhere. Nonetheless, thank you very much for seeing through my faulty failure case and for posting the solution. I am hashing part of the semaphore name now, so the problem is solved.